# Buggenie plugin installation issue

Tags: plugins

I am trying to install / configure buggenie plugin on wordpress (ubuntu 10.04). I get errors in pcre 8.0 version. Did a lot of google search but none resolved the issue, I just got deeper into a worse mess.

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev
```

I then downloaded libpcre 8.0 version, make failed with

```
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/<homedir>/Downloads/pcre-8.30'
  CXX    pcrecpp.lo
libtool: compile: unrecognized option `-DHAVE_CONFIG_H'
libtool: compile: Try `libtool --help' for more information.
make[1]: *** [pcrecpp.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/<homedir>/Downloads/pcre-8.30'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Did a bit more research and found that I need to install g++ and build-essential

```
sudo apt-get install g++
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Yet I get the same error on "make".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 10.04 does not have the required pcre version available. I guess I will need to upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu.